# How can I utilise reactive values without passing them to an output?

Tags: r, shiny

Let's say I have some Shiny/R functionality which generates Javascript on-the-fly, and this JS produces new UI elements which in turn produce reactive values i.e a quantity which can be incremented or decremented.

I am having trouble passing back the values to use on the server side. Consider this minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          shiny::tags$script(htmltools::HTML('
          $(document).on("shiny:connected", function() {
            quantity = 1;
            console.log(quantity);
            Shiny.setInputValue("hi", quantity);
          });'))
       ,
        )
        )
        
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
  sayHi <- reactive({ input$hi })
  
  getHi <- renderText({ sayHi() })
  
  print(getHi) # prints function
  print(getHi()) # error
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I don't want to pass the quantity value straight to an output i.e output$id. Instead, I want to use it in an R function. But I can't "get" to that value. getHi returns the function and getHi() produces, "Operation not allowed without an active reactive context." - but I thought the reactive context was setup by renderText. How can I pass updating values to e.g an R function, without passing them straight to an output?

Comment: You cannot. First, `print` in the middle of a server component makes little sense: the server component is linear in definition but very nonlinear in execution, so having a print statement somewhere in the middle is really only useful when the server is defined, never after that. Second, all of shiny's reactivity is based on the premise that shiny knows which components are accessing a reactive value (not within `isolate(.)`), so there is no attempt to allow access outside of its tightly-controlled reactive blocks.

Comment: When it says *"without an active reactive context"*, that active context is when you are actually *within* a reactive function. For instance, `sayHi()` is within the reactive context of `renderText`, but not within your `print`, so `renderText` is providing that reactive context.

Comment: Okay, so alternatively, could you not setup some i/o pairs, create some JS function which alters the the input of the pair (which would in turn update the output) and then use that output value later on e.g process it and then output it again? You'd just have to chain everything together everything a priori (rather than on-the-fly)?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do with that, and I will defer any JS-shiny interaction questions to daattali  (`{shinyjs}`) or the shiny authors. But frankly, I fail to see how the source of reactive data is an issue: you are trying to access a shiny reactive object in a way that does not make sense. If your JS updates that data, fine ... but you're still trying to access it incorrectly. At the time when `server` is defined (and the only time your `print` will fire) is before `input$hi` exists or has value. The user hasn't been consulted yet.